# How to detect the non-spurious FE_INEXACT?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, language-lawyer

C11, F.10 allows spurious ‘‘inexact’’ floating-point exception to be raised.

C11, F.10 Mathematics <math.h>, 9 (emphasis added):

> Whether or when library functions raise an undeserved ‘‘underflow’’ floating-point
> exception is unspecified.<sup>372)</sup> Otherwise, as implied by F.8.6, the <math.h> functions do
> not raise spurious floating-point exceptions (detectable by the user), **other than the
> ‘‘inexact’’ floating-point exception**.

If `<math.h>` functions may raise spurious `FE_INEXACT`, then how to detect the non-spurious `FE_INEXACT`?

Comment: "how to detect the non-spurious FE_INEXACT?"  I suspect you can't, at least not easily (e.g., without using a separate library to validate). Annex F says nothing about requiring correct rounding for general math functions `sin`, `pow`, ..., and an algorithm that isn't sophisticated enough to do correct rounding is unlikely to be able to correctly implement `FE_INEXACT` (except for cases where the result is mathematically _never_ exact - e.g., `sin`, `tan` and `cos` of anything nonzero). Getting FE_INEXACT right for `pow` in all cases would be particularly computationally expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Fred J. Tydeman (Vice-chair of PL22.11 (ANSI "C")):

> Q: Does it mean that the C Standard provides no reliable way to detect the
> non-spurious `FE_INEXACT`?
>
> A: Correct.